# writing to a file using php ftp

Tags: php

I'm exporting some data, making a file and writing the data to the file...

my file appears on the ftp server, but it's empty...

here is the code.

```
//Connect to the FTP server
$ftpstream = @ftp_connect('localhost');

//Login to the FTP server
$login = @ftp_login($ftpstream, 'some_login', 'some_password');
if($login) {
//We are now connected to FTP server.
//Create a temporary file
$temp = tmpfile();

//Upload the temporary file to server
@ftp_fput($ftpstream, '/httpdocs/itineraryschedule.txt', $temp, FTP_ASCII);

//Make the file writable by all
ftp_site($ftpstream,"CHMOD 0777 /httpdocs/itineraryschedule.txt");

//Write to file
$fp = fopen('var/www/vhosts/cruiseandmaritime.com/httpdocs/itineraryschedule.txt', 'w');
fputs($fp, 'some data');
fclose($fp);

//Make the file writable only to owner
ftp_site($ftpstream,"CHMOD 0644 /httpdocs/itineraryschedule.txt");
}
```

I'm puzzled !

Rich :)

Comment: Get rid of the `@` for starters to *see errors*...?

Comment: why would you first start a connection to a file with the ftp protocol, to later on connect to the file with fopen? Either stick to FTP or FOPEN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the @ to see if any errors occur

Also your path

`$fp = fopen('var/www/vhosts/cruiseandmaritime.com/httpdocs/itineraryschedule.txt', 'w');`

seems a little off

`$fp = fopen('/var/www/vhosts/cruiseandmaritime.com/httpdocs/itineraryschedule.txt', 'w');`
maybe?

Comment: yep that was it ! got rid of the @ - no errors, tried the / in front of var and hey presto ! ni swan @Gabriel Baker

Comment: @Rich, if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as "accepted" answer. You can do this on the top-left of this post. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the library you're using. But the code seems to upload the tmpfile() you've just created before you upload it. That the reason why it is empty.

It seems you write the data you want to push to the FTP-Server locally. `var/www/vhosts/cruiseandmaritime.com/httpdocs/itineraryschedule.txt` is just on your machine. Try to upload it with `ftp_fput` - this should do the trick.