# How can I open a file from another ftp and write?

Tags: php, ftp, connection

I tried to open a file in another ftp and write but I coulnd how can I do that?

```
 $ftpstream = @ftp_connect('****');

 //Login to the FTP server
 $login = @ftp_login($ftpstream, '****', '***');
 if($login) {
 echo "Conectado";
 $fp = fopen('file.txt', 'w');
 fwrite($fp, '1');
 fwrite($fp, '23');
  fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem / error you are getting. You should at least start with removing the error suppressor `@`.

Comment: Already answered - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259659/

Comment: I just wanna write on a file I coulnd undestand this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259659/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted is wrong. It opens up an FTP stream (`ftp_connect`), but then writes a file to the local file system (`fopen`). Your ftp stream won't allow you to write to it with `fwrite`- you need to use the commands to transfer entire files.

You can do what you want with `fopen` if you use an `ftp://` scheme.

For example:

```
$fp = fopen("ftp://user:password@example.com/file.txt","w");
fwrite($fp, '1');
fwrite($fp, '23');
fclose($fp);
```

Alternativley, you can write the file to the local file system and use an ftp stream to transfer it:

```
$file = 'somefile.txt';

// create your file in the local file system here.

$remote_file = 'readme.txt';

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
  echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
  echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

As always, be clear on what you want to do.

PHP FTP reference is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php)

PHP scheme & wrapper reference (for use with `fopen`) is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php)