# How can i edit a txt file using php and ftp

Tags: php, ftp, fopen

I want to edit (write some data) to a txt file located on an ftp server using php.

I looked to this post [writing to a file using php ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259659/writing-to-a-file-using-php-ftp)

but in this case CHMOD 0777 is applied which is not understood by my server.

Comment: So, you question is whether your web server process has access to a file? That depends on file owner, file group, web server userid and groups it belongs to. But since your chmod is 777, everyone shall have access to the file.

Comment: "which is not understood by my server" what does that mean? Do you get an error? What error? What is the platform you are on? Are you sure you need to chmod the thing? Do you know what it does? If not have you checked the manual about what it does?

Comment: Warning: ftp_site() [function.ftp-site]: 'SITE CHMOD 0777 /log/etllog.txt': command not understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as that!

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("ftp://user:password@example.com/somefile.txt", "w");
?>
```

It worked!